# Trying to create a batch file for opening a new tab on Chrome

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts

I want a batch file that can open a specific webpage every time on a new tab in chrome. How can I do it?
The tried script which is very very simple, I guess

@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

start  "--new-tab"  "http://192.168.178.88:8080"

Is there anyone have any idea how its possible to create the batch file script please let me know.

Else if any other alternative idea that will be helpful